# change/override style for antdesign Input component

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I want to change the styling for antdesign Input component and I am not sure how to make it work.
Now, I have been able to change the style on validation success and the border color changes to green on hover.
but still, when I click in the field to type, it still shows blue border.
Now, why is that happening?
How do I override the antdesign styles?

```
<FormItem  hasFeedback validateStatus={this.state.passwordErr} help={passwordHelp}  label="Password" >

            <Input className={validClass}   type="password" name="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handlePassword} />

            </FormItem>
```

this is a small relevant portion.

this css works for the hover

```
 .success:hover{
    border:1px solid green;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px green;
}
```

but this doesnt work when I do it without hover

```
 .success:hover{
    border:1px solid green;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px green;
}
```

I have noticed that this is the portion that is blocking my css

```
.ant-input:focus {
    border-color: #5070f2;
     outline: 0; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(40, 72, 229, 0.2); 
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(40, 72, 229, 0.2);
}
```

So, how do I override this css and force it to use mine?

here's the image of the effect 
i want to change the blue to green.
[image]

and here's the code in inspect
[image]

Comment: Your css has to be [more specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) to override the vendor css.

Answer (score 4):

You overwrite only the styles on :hover, you say that you found that `.ant-input:focus {` is overwriting your styles.

Why don't you write styles for the `:focus` event then ?

```css
    .success:focus {
      border:2px solid red;
     }
```

```html
<input type="text" class="success">
```

If this doesn't work, write a more specific path like `input.success:focus` or `form input.success:focus`

But i guess ( since it's about focus on input elements ) that the problem is with the `outline` which appears on focus

You can either change the outline color/width etc. or hide it with `outline:none` and use your border style

```css
input.success:focus { /*or a more specific selector*/
   outline-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="success">
```

```css
input.success:focus { /*or a more specific selector*/
      outline:none;
      border:3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="success">
```

Comment: although i have tried something like that, let me try that again.

Comment: if your input has 2 classes : success and .ant-input, you can write `.ant-input.success:focus { border:2px solid red;} `

Comment: now, it seems that's not the thing that's blocking.
in the inspect from browser
I changed that to .ant-input:focus {
      border:2px solid red;
     } and I am still getting a blue border, so that's not it

Comment: The problem is with the `outline` . Instead of border set `outline-color:red` . Or set `outline:none` and it will dissapear. THis on `:focus` event with a specific seletor

Comment: Did you see my updated answer ? what styles do you have in your inspect element on that input ? on normal state, hover state and focus state ? which styles are cut out ? or can you show me an image maybe with the effect when you click on the input and the `inspect` element with code ?

Comment: @faraz that is the `outline` + some box shadow. use `.ant-form-input-control input.ant-input, ant-form-input-control input.ant-input:focus { outline:none; box-shadow:none; border:2px solid red;}`

Comment: well, finally had to use inline style to make it work

Comment: @faraz glad i could help. don't forget to rate my answer

Answer (score 1):

I came to the same problem and my solution works well for Antd version4.

```
<Input suffix={<Component />}/>
```

css:

```
.ant-input-affix-wrapper {
  border: ....;
}

.ant-input-affix-wrapper-focused {
  border: ...;
  box-shadow: ...;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use "antd": "^4.24.2", and here is what worked for me.
Add the following to your global css, and import the global css into your root folder.

```
.ant-input-affix-wrapper.ant-input-password {
  border: none;
}

.ant-input-affix-wrapper-focused {
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```